# I just joined without being invited. Is that bad?

Tags: bug, user-accounts

Using the mobile site, I was able to join as if the site was in public beta. I thought you had to be invited to join.

Comment: Can I ask how you found the private beta site? Are you already part of the Monero community or did you find us by accident while looking around on Stack Exchange?

Comment: @David I clicked on the Twitter bot through my phone. It wasn't an accident; I wanted to ask questions about Monero. I just never went through area 51.

Answer (score 7):

Anyone can visit the [Area51 proposal page](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/98617/monero) and click "Visit" :)

It's only private inasmuch as it's not indexed by Google or anything, so it gave us a few weeks to put some content on and figure out the lay of the proverbial land.

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to Monero SE! Everyone is definitely welcome now.

I committed prior to private beta but am under the impression people can still join now if they use the visit link on the Area51 [site](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/98617/monero).

Public beta should be starting in about another week.